# Dynamic arrays inside a dynamic array

Tags: python, arrays, dynamic

I want to create dynamic arrays inside a dynamic array because I dont know how many lists it will take to get the actual result. So using python 2.x when I write

```
Arrays = [[]]
```

does this mean that there is only one dynamic array inside an array or it can mean to be more than one when call for it in for loop like arrays[i]?
If it's not the case do you know a different method?

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. But IMHO, list(array) in Python is really flexible and it can hold elements of any type.

Comment: Are you talking about 2D array ?

Comment: yes @AtulKumar a 2D array with unspecified sizes I guess

Answer (score 1):

Consider using

```
Arrays = []
```

and later, when you are assigning your results use

```
Arrays.append([result])
```

This is assuming that your result comes in slices, but not as an array. No matter your actual return value layout, a variation of the above `.append()` should do the trick, as it allows you to dynamically extend your array. If your result comes as an array, it would simply be

```
Arrays.append(result)
```

and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can just define

```
Arrays = []
```

It is enough to hold your dynamic array.

```
AnotherArray1 = []
AnotherArray2 = []
Arrays.append(AnotherArray1)
Arrays.append(AnotherArray2)
print Arrays
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

If your array is going to be sparse, that is a lot of empty elements, you can consider to have a dict with coordinates as keys instead of nested lists:

```
grid = {}
grid[(x, y)] = value
print(grid)
```

output: `{(x, y): value}`